# Kendoui DropdownList trigger open event (same code used)

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-ui

Ok I am thinking that this might be a bug or something but can't figure it out. I have a table with one row three column, the first cell has a label with a span inside, the second has an empty span with a select element, and the last one has just a span.

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label><span  onclick="revealSiblingEdit(event);">Click Me</span></label>
        </td>
        <td>          
            <span name="select1"></span>
            <select name="Select1" style="display:none">
               <option value="" selected="selected"></option>                
               <option value="1">Yes</option>
               <option value="2">No</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label><span class='lockButton onclick="editDone(event)">Edit</span></label>
        </td>
```

the select element will be hidden and the span with the same name will display the value that was selected. Once the document is loaded I run this code that changes my select elelemnt into a KenndoUI widget, with a function binded to the open event, the open event is trigger when the widget is open by the user. Notice that it is also hidden, and that I am using the class `.k-widget` to find the kendoui Widget and hide it.

```
$("select[name='select1']").kendoDropDownList({
       open: function(e) {
           console.log("maaaannnnnn.......");
       }
    }).closest(".k-widget").hide();
```

*Background info: making the select element be a kendoUI Widget cause it to become a child element of a span, and it also has sibling span which I am going to use later, the select element is still there but hidden and what we see is the span made to look like a select element*

You can hide the span and show the select element by clicking on the span inside thelabel or the edit span. Each has there own function to execute.
First is the `revealSiblingEdit` function executed when you click the span inside the label. What it does is the event containing target (a reference to the element that fired the event) is passed into the function. There I use it to find the span that is enclosing the select element, that span has the attribute `data-role='listbox'`, I also find the span inside the cell which has the same name the select element, as well as the span element that is the Edit. It then calls the showAndHideInput function, after calling that function it then changes the content of the edit span to Edit or Done.

```
function revealSiblingEdit(e) {     
var thisTarget = e.target;    
var theSiblingInput = $(thisTarget).closest("tr").find("span[role='listbox']");             
   var theSiblingSpan = $(thisTarget).closest("tr").find("span[name*='" + theSiblingInput.find("select").attr("name") + "']");
   } 
   var theDoneButton = $(thisTarget).parents("td").siblings().find(".lockButton");     
   showAndHideInput(theSiblingInput, theSiblingSpan, theDoneButton);     

   if ($(theDoneButton).text() == "Edit") {
       $(theDoneButton).text("Done");
   } else {
       $(theDoneButton).text("Edit");
   }
```

}

By clicking the edit span it execute the function `editDone`, which does **exactly the same thing** as `revealSiblingEdit`. The only difference is that the event passed to the function already contains a reference to the edit span so we do not need to find it.

```
function editDone(e) {        
var thisTarget = e.target;
var theSiblingInput = $(thisTarget).closest("tr").find("span[role='listbox']");
var theSiblingSpan = $(thisTarget).closest("tr").find("span[name*='" + theSiblingInput.find("select").attr("name") + "']");   
showAndHideInput(theSiblingInput, theSiblingSpan, thisTarget);
if ($(thisTarget).text() == "Edit") {
    $(thisTarget).text("Done");
} else {
    $(thisTarget).text("Edit");
}
```

}

Now for the showAndHideInput function that both calls. It check to see what "mode" we are in. If the edit span content is `Edit` then we are entering edit mode and will display the kendoUI widget for the use to interact with and hide the select1 span element. It first checks to see if there is anything in the  span element, (if there is that means there is a value from before and set the value of the kendoUI to that value as default). If the edit span content is Done, that means we are done with edit mode. So we will then get the new value the the user selected and change the content of the select1 span element to that. Then hide the KendoUI widget and show the span. I have a for loop because there can be more than one select and span element in each cell.

```
function showAndHideInput(theInput, theSpan, theBtn) {
console.log(theBtn);
var theData;
var index;
if ($(theBtn).text() == "Edit") {       
    for (index = 0; index < theInput.length; index++) {
        theData = $(theSpan[index]).text();            
        $(theInput[index]).val(theData);
        $(theInput[index]).css('display', 'inline-block');           
        $(theSpan[index]).css('display', 'none');
    }
} else {
    for (index = 0; index < theInput.length; index++) {            
        if ($(theInput[index]).is("span[role='listbox']")) {
            theData = $(theInput[index]).find(".k-input").text();               
        } else if (($(theInput[index]).attr("class") == "CheckBox")) { //check to see if the element is a checkbox element
            //do nothing, check box are not readonly and are automatically editable
        } else {
            theData = $(theInput[index]).val();               
        }
        if ($(theSpan[index]).text() != theData) {                
            $(theSpan[index]).text(theData);               
        }          
        //  $(theInput[index]).css('display', 'none');            
        $(theInput[index]).hide();
        $(theSpan[index]).show();
    }
}
```

}

Now here is the problem. When ever I click on the click me span in the label the open event is fired, but when I click on the edit span it does not fire the open event. If I where to go to edit mode by clicking the span in the label then go out of edit mode by clicking the edit span it does not fire the open event, but if I where to go to edit mode by clicking the edit span the go out of edit mode by clicking the span in the label it fires the open event. This causes a problem becuase for some reason what ever causes it the fire the open event also makes the list for the drop down list appear in the top right corner. I don't know why it is doing this, but as I was typing this I was able to find out what was causing it. Apparently it did not like the fact that my span was inside the label, once I just have the label by itself the open event stopped firing and the drop down list stopped appearing. Do anybody know why it did not like the span being inside the label? Becuase before I used the kendoUI widget it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Would you mind putting this code in a jsbin? If we could see the problem in action, it would really help.